# Let $u$ be harmonic on domain $D\subset \mathbb R^d$, how far can we extend $u$ holomorphically?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

If $u$ is harmonic then it is real analytic so then it can be extended locally holomorphically. I also know that if $u$ is harmonic on a ball in $\mathbb R^d$ we have that the radius of convergence is at least the radius of the ball (see https://www.um.es/beca/NoLiFA/charlas/talk_Ryan_NoLiFA.pdf slide 15).

To clarify, I want to extend to a holomorphic function on some subset of $\mathbb C^d$ and NOT to a larger subset of $\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: A real-analytic function on an open set $D \subset \mathbb R^d$ need not extend beyond $D$ at all.  For a function of $2$ or more real variables, what is the definition of "radius of convergence"?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I am not interested in extending in $\mathbb R^d$, I am interested in extending holomorphically.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar To clarify further, I want a function defined on some subset of $\mathbb C^d$

Comment: So: you want to find $f$ holomorphic on a region $D_1 \supset D$ in $\mathbb C^d$ with $f=u$ on $D$  .  I think we know how to do this when $d=1$.  And you ask about larger $d$.  I added the tag `several-complex-variables`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See a similar question  I asked some times ago. Due to P. Lelong and J. Siciak it is known that, if $D\subset\mathbb R^n$ ($n\geq 2$) is a domain, then there exists a domain $\tilde D\subset\mathbb C^n$, $D\subset\tilde D$, such that every harmonic function on $D$ extends to a holomorphic function on $\tilde D$. In the case that $D$ is the real unit ball the maximal $\tilde D$ is given by the Lie-ball (due to M. Jarnicki).

Comment: Hi, can you give reference for these? Thank you very much.

Comment: @PeterPflug I am confused. Every convex domain is trivially pseudoconvex, thus there exists a holomorphic function that can't be extended beyond. Now  consider ellipsoids $G_a: x_1^2+\cdots +x_d^2+a(y_1^2+\cdots+y_d^2)<1$. The intersection $G_a\cap\mathbb{R}^d$ is a unit ball, and the intersection of $G_a$ for $a\to\infty$ is also a unit ball. That means that there is no domain that you can extend any harmonic function from the unit ball.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin I can't follow your argument at all. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Dear user479223: P. Lelong: Prolongement ...., Bull. Soc. Math. Belgique 7(1954), 10-23; J.Siciak: Holomorphic continuation of harmonic functions, Ann.Pol.Math. XXIX (1974), 67-73; M.Jarnicki: Analytic continuation ... Zeszyty Nauk. Uniw. Jagiellonskiego 17(1975),93-104.

Comment: Oh. I was confused. The restriction of a holomorphic function on a real subspace is not harmonic in general.